# How to use a single tough-cookie cookie jar throughout multiple Express routes (in different files)?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have an Express API on NodeJS which obtains information of a user to a website that requires login. The `login` route logs in a user to its online account (using `node-fetch` requests). During the process, a bunch of cookies (sessions and others) are set use `tough-cookie` `CookieJar()` and hence stored to the websites. I need this since I make multiple requests in login and each request depends on the cookies being stored on each specific website (mainly redirects).

Now, I have another route, `email` (in a separate file), which obtains (using a GET request) the email address of the logged in user. However, I noticed when I make the GET request to the `email` route, it returns the page for the user to login and not the expected JSON object of the user's e-mail. I would think that the cookie jar from the login route would persist from the other page but it has not. How would I be able to use a single cookie jar throughout multiple routes (in different files)?

tough-cookie GitHub repository (with information on its methods): https://github.com/salesforce/tough-cookie

Code:

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use('/email', require('./email'))
app.use('/login', require('./login'))

app.listen(port)
```

`login.js`

```js
const express = require('express')

const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const router = express.Router()
const tough = require('tough-cookie')
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()

const handleRedirect = (response) => {
    // Stores cookies to cookie jar on each redirect
}

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // Multiple fetch requests
})

module.exports = router
```

`email.js`

```js
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fetch("<link to website for user's email JSON object>")
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => res.send(data)) // Problem here: Just returns the HTML of the login page of the website
        .catch(error => console.log("Error: "+error))  
})

module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a way to do it. I first had to use an `express-session` in the `server.js` file. Then, set the `req.session.cookieJar = cookieJar` on the last `node-fetch` request in the `login` route. Finally, `deserialize` the `req.session.cookieJar` in the `email` route by doing this:

```js
const tough = require('tough-cookie')
var cookieJar = null

tough.CookieJar.deserialize(req.session.cookieJar, (error, deserializedJar) => {
    if (error) throw new Error("Failed to deserialize.")
    cookieJar = deserializedJar
 })
```

Full code:

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
})
app.use('/email', require('./email'))
app.use('/login', require('./login'))
app.listen(port)
```

`login.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const tough = require('tough-cookie')

const router = express.Router()
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()

const handleRedirect = (response) => {
    // Stores cookies to cookieJar (using setCookie) on each redirect
}

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    // Multiple fetch requests and calls handleRedirect after every request
    // Set req.session.cookieJar = cookieJar on last fetch request
})

module.exports = router
```

`email.js`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const tough = require('tough-cookie')

const router = express.Router()
var cookieJar = null

router.get('/', (req, res) => {]
    tough.CookieJar.deserialize(req.session.cookieJar, (error, deserializedJar) => {
        if (error) throw new Error("Failed to deserialize.")
        cookieJar = deserializedJar
 })

    fetch("<node-fetch URL>", {
        headers: {
            cookie: cookieJar.getCookieStringSync("<node-fetch URL>")
        }    
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => res.send(data))
        .catch(error => console.log("Error: "+error))
})

module.exports = router
```